# Evenly skewing a rectangle (= turning it into a trapezoid): Calculating the length of the base

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I have a basic rectangle, which I want to skew to give the illusion of perspective (I'm creating a Python program). [Here's what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmxb8.png) The angles in the picture are just exemplary; I want this to be dynamic. However, the "offset" is always identical (so out of the four degrees, two of each are the same.)

How do I calculate the length of a, given c, b, d and every angle? [This site](https://www.mathepower.com/trapez.php) claims that the equation to do so (using the available information) is

$a = \frac{b*sin(-\alpha-\beta+180) + c*sin(\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)}$

(Googleable:)

```
a = (b*sin(-alpha-beta+180) + c*sin(alpha))/(sin(alpha))
```

and gives the correct length for an exemplary rectangle I tried it with. (Since the site is in German, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gOMr.png) is the relevant part.)

HOWEVER, feeding this equation into Google, Python, or even [a different part of this very site](https://www.mathepower.com/terme.php?gle=%28250%2Asin%28-45-45%2B180%29%2B850%2Asin%2845%29%29%2Fsin%2845%29), it gives a different result (one which does not "work out"). Yes, I checked for radiant/degree. I also tried different transcriptions of the equation.

All the other approaches I could find required knowledge of A, m or h (which all require a in some shape or form).

Anybody know either the correct equation to calculate a (knowing what I know, so, not h, m or A), or a different online calculator (which also gives the equation - again, I want to make it dynamic)?

Thanks a ton in advance!

(In case anybody wants to toy around with the equation; using possible numbers, it is

```
(250*sin(-45-45+180)+850*sin(45))/sin(45)
```

That way you don't have to transcribe it yourself. The correct result is 1203.553; however, I always get 1112.661 using the equation myself)

Comment: If you want to give the illusion of perspective, a good way consists in computing the intersection with the plane of the image, of a ray from the object to the observer. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)#Overview.

Comment: If you want to do actual perspectives and not just an illusion, I'd look into homographies and projective planes.

Comment: The given/skewed  rectangles should have both labeled lengths $(b,b)$ and trapezium inclined sides as $(d,d)$ ; right?

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula is

$ a = c + b \cos \alpha + d \cos \beta $

where $\alpha $ is the angle between $b$ and $a$ , and $\beta$ is the angle between $d$ and $a$.

If $\alpha = \beta = 45^\circ $, and $b = d = 250$, and $ c = 850 $, then

$ a = 850 + 250 \sqrt{2} = 1203.55 $

which is the correct result.